# Can't add IDFA list to custom segment in iAd Workbench - My audiences

Tags: iad, idfa, audience

I can't create a custom audience using a list of IDFA file.
When I'm upload a plain text (.txt) file that contains the users IDFA appears the error message - 'Failed. Server error. Please try again later'

[image: File upload status]

Everyone is doing so, it is written in the instructions: [iAd Workbench: Create and edit audience segments](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH23002?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US)
But I note that for emails list this working properly!
What am I doing wrong for IDFA?

My IDFA file has this format:

ECF0F1EA-BF46-40DC-B98A-18491D37533A
AEA3B781-9814-46DE-A9A2-BDD4557263C8
3C09B242-0B4F-435A-B2CC-88FB3E9B76B2
...

Answer (score 0):

Today I received an email from Apple Support maybe it will be someone useful.

> Thank you for contacting Apple about your iAd issue, my name is Pia
>   and I’m happy to assist you.
>
> First of all, please let me apologise for the delay in getting back to
>   you. I understand that you are experiencing an error message when
>   creating audience >segments. For privacy reasons, we are unable to
>   review IDFA files. I would like to direct >you to this link where you
>   can see detailed instructions on how to create and >edit audience
>   segments:
>
> https://help.apple.com/iadworkbench/mac/2.0/#/slvda32b7a12
>
> I hope this helps, thank you for your cooperation.
>
> Kind regards,
>
> Pia Apple Inc.

So, now they just don't review IDFA files